# WHMCS PHP Include

Tags: javascript, php, html, smarty, whmcs

I am trying to include `analytic.php` into `head.tpl` in WHMCS but it keep giving me a error.

> Analytic.php location : root/analytic.php
>
> Head.tpl location : root/whmcs/template/six/includes/head.tpl

I saw on google, WHMCS accept smarty PHP, so i am trying to include with Smarty PHP Code in `head.tpl`.

Code :

```
{include_php file="../../../../analytic.php"};
```

Also Tried  :

```
{php}{include_php file="../../../../analytic.php"};{/php}
```

Note : I have already enabled Smarty PHP in WHMCS

But when i am entering the code, the WHMCS site get stop working :(. What the solution to include PHP file inside **WHMCS** or **.tpl** file?

Answer (score 0):

include_php is depreced as of Smarty 3.1.
`{php}NO!{include_php file="../../../../analytic.php"};NO!{/php}` is totally wrong.

you should create 'analytics.tpl' file and then include it `{include}`, file can contain analytics script.

Comment: something like this `{include_php file="../../../../analytic.tpl"}` without `{php} & {/php}`

Comment: no! I said that include_php is depreced. `{include file="../../../../analytic.tpl"}`

Comment: I tried this same code too but not working :(

Comment: did you manually create analytics.tpl file? (check on server is it exist and check proper src directory)

Answer (score 0):

To include a file in WHMCS do

```
{include file="analytic.tpl"}
```

Inside your analytic.tpl you can use PHP with

```
{php}
echo "works";
{/php}
```

You also must activate this function inside your WHMCS Admin Area.

- Navigate to: "System Settings - General Settings".
- Switch to Tab "Security".
- Search for "Allow Smarty PHP Tags" and activate it.

You should consider to move to hooks instead of PHP-Code inside your templates: https://developers.whmcs.com/themes/php/